# Pass commands to Mongo shell from bash script without halting interactive Mongo shell

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, shell

I am looking to create a bash script which connects to a remote Mongo database and initializes an interactive Mongo shell, issues a couple of commands to the interactive Mongo shell, and then enables the interactive shell to continue running so that I can continue entering commands into it.

Currently, I understand that I can connect to a Mongo database and issue a command to it within a bash script like so:

```
mongo <ip>:<port>/<database> --eval "db.auth('myuname', 'mypass');"
```

However, I would like my bash script to run the above command, and then keep the Mongo shell that was initialized running so that I can continue to use it and enter commands into it on my own. It seems that after running the above command, a Mongo shell is created and then halted immediately after the given `db.auth()` command is executed, but I would like to keep the shell running past this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`--shell`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo/#cmdoption--shell) option in addition to the `--eval` option. This will keep the mongo shell session open in interactive mode after the `--eval` code is run:

```
mongo --shell --eval "printjson('Hello, World!')"
```

You can also put commands in `~/.mongorc.js` and `/etc/mongorc.js` that the shell will run when it is started by the current user or every time it is started, respectively. See the [files section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files) of the mongo shell docs.